# Rails 3 model mapping certain columns to different model attributes

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, legacy

I have the old legacy table called "DXFTACCTS", and I created Rails model "Account".

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "DXFTACCTS"
end
```

The problem is that DXFTACCTS has fields like "XORFNAME" which I want to be "first_name" in the model, and so on. How do I "map" specific table columns to model attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the method alias_attribute like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "DXFTACCTS"

  alias_attribute :first_name, :XORFNAME
end
```

alias_attribute creates the methods first_name, first_name= and first_name? which will map to the XORFNAME column in your table. However, you will NOT be able to use it in conditions like regular columns. For example:

```
Account.all(:conditions => { :first_name => "Foo" })
```

That will fail...

Answer (score 2):

I think something like definition of getter and setter methods should do the trick:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base    

  ...

  def firts_name
    self[:XORFNAME]
  end

  def first_name= value
    self[:XORFNAME] = value 
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :-(

Comment: DanneManne below proposed a short and better way that I didn't know before.