# Rails map columns of excel file to db columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, sqlite

I am working on a engine, where i am parsing a excel file using `Roo` gem. The problem i am facing is that i don't know how to map columns.

For e.g. my `db-table` have columns `first_name`, `last_name`, `emp_id`, `designation` etc. But my excel file can have any column name for e.g. it could be `fname`, `lname`, `e_id`, `designation` or it could be `FirstName`, `LastName`, `EmployeeId` etc.

Now how do i map data such that it will get stored in the respective column.

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073823/rails-3-model-mapping-certain-columns-to-different-model-attributes) but how do i set alias as my excel column header can be anything. If can alias than please tell me how i can do that. Its my first time i am working on rails engine. Also i am new to ruby.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than using dynamic database columns, it might be easier to serialize the csv into a string and store in the database that way

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of stuff I would use a service object.

```ruby
class ImportExcel
   DEFAULT_MAPPING = {
      excel_col_name => db_colname
   }.freezy

   def initialize(mapping=nil, model_class=nil)
      @mapping = mapping || DEFAULT_MAPPING
      @model_class = model_class || DefaultModelClass
   end

   def import(excel_sheet)
      records = []
      header = excel_sheet.first_row 
      2.upto(excel_sheet.last_row) do |line|  
        record = @model_class.new
        records << record
        header.each_with_index do |name, col|
           record[@mapping[name]]= excel_sheet.row[line][col]
        end
      end
      records
   end
end

# Where ever
importer = ImportExcel.new({ a: :b , c: :d}, MyModel)
new_records = importer.import(sheet)
new_records.map(&:save!)
```

Comment: well i want to save the data in db. Your mapping seems to work but hw will you save array to db.

Comment: You can call record.save! after header... end or imorter.import(...).map(&:save!)

Comment: I have one more doubt. Actually i am building a engine, so My engine will only give columns and data to model of app and than my engine will save that data to db. How do we map data in that case.

Comment: I'm not shure what you mean. I think you mean the Importer is within the enginge und your app calls the Importer. But your engine knows nothing about the mapping, which has to take place. In this case I would make `MAPPING` an instance variable and fill it from within app to have the right mapping.

Comment: it didn't work. Engine is unable to recognize the table

Comment: The model class is within the app and not the engine? I will adjust the code

Comment: yeah please, i am really getting confused as i am new to rails.

Comment: can you write separate code for both app's model and engin'e model

Comment: Sorry, no I can't do this because it depends on your current implementation. I don't know what's inside your engine and whats inside your app and so on. I think this exceeds a simple stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

If excel column sequence is fixed than you can store data like this:

```
@xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, extension: :xls)
for i in 2..@xls.last_row
  Table.create(first_name: @xls.row(i)[1],last_name: @xls.row(i)[2],..)
end
```

Hope it will help you...

Comment: your answer works for small excel files but when there are many columns in db than this code will get bigger. Is there any way that `Table.create(first_name: @xls.row(i)[1],last_name: @xls.row(i)[2],..)` this code can be optimized

Comment: If we not sure for column name then we need to do this, but let me try for optimize..if i succeed I will comment here.